# Server side rules in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange

Using Outlook 2007 with an Exchange Server.

I am trying to setup a server-side rule, but regardless of what I do, it always sets up a client-only rule.

I am trying to copy a message to a folder if it comes from a certain person and the subject contains certain words.

What am I missing?

Update: It seems that setting the rule to mark the message read-only forces the message to be client-side.  Anyway to get around that?

Comment: You should write ALL the rules you are using if you want help. It's not good updating/adding information after people try to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Anything that needs to be done on the client will become a client-side rule, eg are you displaying a desktop alert as part of the rule?

Comment: No, I am not display anything.  Just want the message to go to a certain folder.